# Can't figure out my error on this assignment dealing with Scanner, file input, nextLine() and etc

Tags: java

I'm trying to read how many words are in each line of a text file, which is working. But, when I get to the end of the text and no more lines exist the program keeps looking for another line and giving me an error. I can't figure out how to get it to stop looking for the next line when none exists.

I've tried a series of if statements and while loops both with using `input.hasNextLine()` and without. I've also tried rearranging where `aString = input.nextLine()` is placed throughout the main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  String fileID = args[0];
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileID));      
  String aString;
  do {
     aString = input.nextLine();
     if(aString.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(quoted(aString)+" contains "+
                           wordCount(aString) + " words!");
     }
  } while(aString.length() > 0);
  System.out.println(quoted(aString)+" contains "+
                     wordCount(aString) + " words!");
  System.out.println("Done!!!");
   }

public static int wordCount(String text) {
  int words = 0;
  char firstCh = text.charAt(0);    
  if (firstCh != ' ') {
     words = words + 1;
  }    
  for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++) {
     char secondCh = text.charAt(i);
     if (firstCh == ' ' && secondCh != ' ') {
        words = words + 1;
     } 
     firstCh = secondCh;
  }    
  return words;
}
```

My input is correct, but I'm getting an error because the program keeps looking for the next line (or so I believe).

> "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal." contains 30 words!
>
> "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this." contains 72 words!
>
> "But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth." contains 176 words!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at wordCountDriver.main(wordCountDriver.java:25)
```

Comment: Please show us the most promising version where you tried to check for the last line.

Comment: Mistake is probably on the do... will check carefully in a bit but im guessing its there

Comment: `while (input.hasNextLine())` don't use a `do while`, because the file *could* be empty.

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast it was with the do loop.  @ Elliott Frisch you were right I switched it around and used just the while. Thank you both and everyone else who commented.

Comment: `String aString = ""; while (input.hasNextLine()) { aString = input.nextLine().trim(); if (aString.equals("")) { continue; } System.out.println("\"" + aString + "\" contains " + aString.split("\\s+").length + " words."); } // Done`

Answer (score 0):

Before reading the line you should actually check if the next line exists or not like below.

```
 while(input.hasNext()){
            String aString = input.nextLine();
            if(aString.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(aString+" contains "+
                        wordCount(aString) + " words!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything.